# Keep a given ID in URL upon successful login

Tags: php, session, authentication

```
    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $id = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session
            setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session
    $goHere = 'Location: /index2.php?id=' . $id;
    header($goHere);
    exit;
}
```

I have the following code that once logged in, it `$_GET` the id and prepends to the url like `index2.php?id=5` . How do I keep this `id=5` in the URL no matter WHAT link they click on??

This id is grabbed from this:

```
        $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $id = $row['id'];
```

**What I want to do**
Well way i have it setup, you login, it then sends you to the homepage such as **index2.php?id=[someint]** , if you click another link say 'prof.php', it removes the `id=[someint]` part, I want to keep it there in the url, so as long as a user is LOGGED in -- using my code above, the url might read: index.php?id=5, then go to another page it might read prof.php?id=5, etc, etc. This *integer* would obviously be dynamic depending on WHO logged in

Comment: What you're trying to do is best achieved via a SESSION variable, not a query string.

Comment: What happens if they hack up the url and set it to id=4, which happens to be an admin account? You should never pass around authentication data in a url like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string isn't the place for that, for a whole host of reasons. The most obvious one is that I can log in with a valid account, then change the number in the URL and it'll think I'm someone else.

Instead, just continue using the session as it's the proper way.

If you REALLY want to do it, you'd probably want to write a custom function for generating links

```
function makeLink ($link, $queryString = '')
{
    return $link . '?id=' . (int) $_SESSION['id'] . ((strpos($queryString, '?') === 0) ? substr($queryString, 1) : $queryString);
}
```

called like

```
<a href="<?php echo makeLink('index2.php', 'query=string&foo=bar'); ?>">Click me</a>
```

As a basic auth example using the ID...

```
<?php
// Session start and so on here
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    // Not logged in
    header('Location: /login.php');
    exit;
}
```

http://www.knowledgesutra.com/forums/topic/7887-php-simple-login-tutorial/ is a pretty straightforward full example of it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing around an ID in the URL, consider referring to the id value in the $_SESSION variable.  That way the user can't modify the URL and see data they aren't supposed to see (or much worse), and you don't have to worry over appending it to every URL and reading it into a value every time you go to process a script.  When the user logs in, you determine their ID - read it from a database, determine it realtime, whatever.  Then store it in the $_SESSION and refer to it as needed.  You can even use this as part of a check to see if the user is logged in - if they have no $_SESSION['id'] value, something is wrong and you make them log in.

Comment: Exactly... consider what would happen if I see my URL is index.php?id=1 and decide to incriment that by 1? Suddenly I get another user's data?

Comment: Yeah, GET values have their uses - but a unique id value is not one.  In this case you wouldn't even have anything to compare it to to know if it's been modified.

Comment: _Would you guys mind showing me how to implement this in my code_. I now do understand where your coming from, and I'm happy I asked here cause its helping me to learn some of this lower level security of web apps

Comment: I've updated my answer with a basic example, and a link to a fuller example if you want to have a quick look :)